# KeyError: Not Found in Axis during pd.DataFrame.drop()

Tags: python, pandas, keyerror

I am playing with the [Accidental Drug Related Deaths 2012-2018](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/accidental-drug-related-deaths-january-2012-sept-2015) dataset. I am using the following `drugs` array:

```
array(['Heroin', 'Cocaine', 'Fentanyl', 'FentanylAnalogue', 'Oxycodone',
       'Oxymorphone', 'Ethanol', 'Hydrocodone', 'Benzodiazepine',
       'Methadone', 'Amphet', 'Tramad', 'Morphine_NotHeroin',
       'Hydromorphone', 'Other', 'OpiateNOS', 'AnyOpioid'], dtype=object)
```

The dataset comes with these pre-one-hot-encoded. I'm trying to convert them to a single column then remove the original features:

```
deaths['DrugDeath'] = deaths[drugs].idxmax(1)
deaths = deaths.drop(drugs)
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "['Heroin' 'Cocaine' 'Fentanyl' 'FentanylAnalogue' 'Oxycodone'\n 'Oxymorphone' 
'Ethanol' 'Hydrocodone' 'Benzodiazepine' 'Methadone'\n 'Amphet' 'Tramad' 'Morphine_NotHeroin'
 'Hydromorphone' 'Other'\n 'OpiateNOS' 'AnyOpioid'] not found in axis"
```

What confuses me about this is not only the error, but also the fact that this was not the format that I input. I put in an array. Now, as per the [pd.DataFrame.drop() documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html), I need a "single label or list-like." Unsure of what "list-like" means or whether an array qualifies, I decided to try `deaths = deaths.drop(drugs.tolist())`, but to no avail.

What is this error, and what does it mean? Why is it responding to a structure of my input that I didn't use? How do I correctly implement this?

Comment: An ndarray will work. What did the docs say about the axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'll fully understand this without seeing your full code, what your `deaths` df looks like, etc, but maybe try:

```py
deaths = deaths.drop(columns=list(drugs))
```